# Python based magento consumer

Tags: php, python, magento, oauth

In extension to my question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/36847384/658209

I was thinking of using OAuth1Session from requests_oauthlib to retrieve access token and access token secret value. I want to do something similar to what is being done in below example:

```
<?php
/**
* Example of OAuth authorization n using Admin account via Magento REST API.
*/
$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://magentohost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" .
urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://magentohost/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://magentohost/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://magentohost/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'yourconsumerkey';
$consumerSecret = 'yourconsumersecret';
session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
$_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
$authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION :
OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
$oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret,
OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
$oauthClient->enableDebug();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {68
$requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
$_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
$_SESSION['state'] = 1;
header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
exit;
} else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
$oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
$accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
echo "oauth_token:".$accessToken['oauth_token']."<br/>";
echo "oauth_token_secret:".$accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
exit;
} else {
echo "authorisation failed";
}
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
print_r($e);
}
```

I have come up with the following code:

```
class Magento_Oauth_Admin(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        return render_template('magentosetup.html')

    def post(self):
        consumer_key=request.form.get('consumer_key')
        consumer_secret=request.form.get('consumer_secret')
        magentourl=request.form.get('magentourl')

        session['magentourl']=magentourl
        callbackurl = api.url_for(Magento_Access_Token)
        temporary_credentials_request_url = '{magentourl}/oauth/initiate?{callbackurl}'.format(magentourl, urllib.urlencode(
            dict(oauth_callback=callbackurl)))
        admin_authorization_url = '{magentourl}/admin/oauth_authorize'.format(magentourl)
        oauth_session = OAuth1Session(consumer_key, client_secret=consumer_secret, callback_uri=callbackurl)
        # First step, fetch the request token.
        fetch_response = oauth_session.fetch_request_token(temporary_credentials_request_url)
        session['resource_owner_key'] = fetch_response.get('oauth_token')
        session['resource_owner_secret'] = fetch_response.get('oauth_token_secret')

        # Second step. Follow this link and authorize
        authorization_url = oauth_session.authorization_url(admin_authorization_url)
        return redirect(authorization_url)

class Magento_Access_Token(restful.Resource):
    """ The user has been redirected back from the provider to the registered
    callback URL. With this redirection comes an authorization code included
    in the redirect URL. We will use that to obtain an access token."""
    def get(self):
        access_token_request_url = '{magentourl}/oauth/token'.format(session['magentourl'])
        verifier = request.args.get('oauth_verifier')

        oauth = OAuth1Session(consumer_key,
                                  client_secret=consumer_secret,
                                  resource_owner_key=session['resource_owner_key'],
                                  resource_owner_secret=session['resource_owner_secret'],
                                  verifier=verifier)
        oauth_tokens = oauth.fetch_access_token(access_token_request_url)
        resource_owner_key = oauth_tokens.get('oauth_token')
        resource_owner_secret = oauth_tokens.get('oauth_token_secret')
        return render_template('magentosetupcomplete.html')


api.add_resource(Magento_Oauth_Admin,"/v2/generateaccesstoken/",endpoint="generateaccesstoken")
api.add_resource(Magento_Access_Token,"/v2/callback/",endpoint="callback")
```

I am not sure how to handle callback and redirects instead of asking the user to go to authorization_url and then paste the redirect url

EDIT: After reading Robbie's comment I have updated my code and split it into 2 endpoints. So now flow of my application is something like:

1. User goes to magentosetup.html and enters consumer token,secret and their magento instance url. They submit this form
2. We get the credentials from above form into Magento_Oauth_Admin post and then we trigger the oAuth dance to generate access token and secret.
3. Once the access token is generated I will store it somewhere(not written that code here)

My question now is in the final step (after the provider redirects user to consumer API, after user authorization), will I be able to redirect the user to magentosetupcomplete.html by using `return render_template('magentosetupcomplete.html')` to confirm to the user that the access token has been generated and saved. I am asking this because the /callback endpoint has been called from magento. I am not sure what the flow of control is in this situation.

Comment: If you can't handle the redirect automatically then you'll need to give the user the URL and ask them to copy and paste it. Unfortunately this is a necessary part of the OAuth process. If you don't want to do that or you can't, you can always utilize the SOAP API instead.

Comment: When you say handle redirect automatically what do you mean. I can do flask.redirect(authorization_url) but then does the control come back to the application on the callback url ? how do I handle the callback? Should there be a separate endpoint that should handle the callback?

Comment: Yes, you will need a separate endpoint for the callback

Comment: To be clear, you send the user to Magento to authorise the OAuth connection, then after the accept it in Magento it will redirect the user back to your application at the callback you specify when you initiate the token request